# How can I Insert several columns from one table to another having only 1 column unique/distinct?

Tags: sql, db2, derby

I am trying to create a star schema and am currently working on the dimension tables. I want to copy several columns from one table to another but at the same time I want to make the result values unique by 1 of the columns.

These are the tables I am using:
DWH_PRICE_PAID_RECORDS

```
CREATE TABLE "DWH_PRICE_PAID_RECORDS" ("TRANSACTION_ID" VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, "PRICE" INTEGER, "DATE_OF_TRANSFER" DATE NOT NULL, "PROPERTY_TYPE" CHAR(1), "OLD_NEW" CHAR(1), "DURATION" CHAR(1), "TOWN_CITY" VARCHAR(50), "DISTRICT" VARCHAR(50), "COUNTY" VARCHAR(50), "PPDCATEGORY_TYPE" CHAR(1), "RECORD_TYPE" CHAR(1));

 ALTER TABLE "DWH_PRICE_PAID_RECORDS" ADD CONSTRAINT "PK3" PRIMARY KEY ("TRANSACTION_ID");
```

and DIM_REGION

```
CREATE TABLE "DIM_REGION" ("REGION_ID" INTEGER generated always as identity (start with 1 increment by 1), "TRANSACTION_ID" VARCHAR(50), "TOWN" VARCHAR(50), "COUNTY" VARCHAR(50), "DISTRICT" VARCHAR(50), "LATITUDE" VARCHAR(50), "LONGITUDE" VARCHAR(50), "COUNTRY_STRING" VARCHAR(50));

ALTER TABLE "DIM_REGION" ADD CONSTRAINT "PK8" PRIMARY KEY ("REGION_ID");
```

My first attempt was to use "select distinct" but that only removes all duplicates of ALL columns combined. I want to have a region dimension and the "town" should be the identifier to match DIM_REGION with the fact table on the data mart that I will create later (called DM_PRICE_PAID_RECORDS).

The DWH_PRICE_PAID_RECORDS table has around 10k records but only 938 unique towns. I want to have those 938 towns in the dim_region as ID along with other columns such as county, district etc.

This is what works but then of course everything else is NULL but town:

```
INSERT INTO DIM_REGION (TOWN) SELECT (town_city) from DWH_PRICE_PAID_RECORDS GROUP BY town_city;
```

So I thought I only have to add additional columns

```
INSERT INTO DIM_REGION (TOWN, County, District) SELECT town_city, county, district from DWH_PRICE_PAID_RECORDS GROUP BY town_city;
```

but when I do that I get this error message (the error message is german and I  had to translate, sorry):

```
ERROR 42Y36 Column reference: "DWH_PRICE_PAID_RECORDS.COUNTY" is invalid or part of a invalid statement. When using SELECT and GROUP BY the selected columns and statements must be valid group- or aggregation expressions.
```

Can you help me or do you have another idea how else I could get the result I seek?

Thank you very much!

Comment: So you want only 1 row for each town, but what about the other 2 columns of the row? What values should they have? There may be many counties for each town and many districts, but you want only 1 of them. Does it matter which county and district it will be?

Comment: Hello @forpas You got it all correct. The other rows dont matter to me and can be removed. My issue is that I dont have anything else as identifier that I could use to join DWH_price_paid_records with DIM_region other than the town name. But therefore it must be unique. The data I have just isnt that great. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the other 2 columns don't matter, you can do this:

```
INSERT INTO DIM_REGION (TOWN, County, District) 
SELECT town_city, MAX(county), MAX(district) 
FROM DWH_PRICE_PAID_RECORDS 
GROUP BY town_city
```

This will get you only 1 row for each town.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much @forpas ;) 

Now Im curious how it could be solved if the other values would matter tho :-P

Comment: It could not be solved, unless you want specific values for the other columns.

Answer (score 1):

You are so close!

```
INSERT INTO DIM_REGION (TOWN, County, District) SELECT town_city, county, district from DWH_PRICE_PAID_RECORDS GROUP BY town_city, county, district;
```

That should do the job. When using a group by, everything in the SELECT list that isn't an aggregate has to appear in the GROUP BY clause.

As an aside, does TRANSACTION_ID really belong in the dimension table?

Comment: Hello Tad, yes your statement works but I thought I could make it unique with column "town" only. Now the group by has the same effect as "Select distinct". I have the same outcome of 1439 lines, but the unique amount of towns is only 936. How could I achieve that? 

Yes, you are absolutely right. The TRANSACTION_ID is useless.

Thank you very much!!